# How do I ignore a directory in the root of my git repository, but include it further down in the tree?

Tags: git

I need to use `.gitignore` to exclude a directory in the root of my repository.  However, other directories with the same name exist deeper in the directory tree, and I need those to be included.  It seems that when I put the name of the directory into `.gitignore`, it catches all of these directories, not just the one I need to ignore.  I understand that `.gitignore` is actually not a list of files, but patterns.  So how can I construct a pattern to ignore just a file in my root directory, but not files with the same name further down?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use a leading /

```
  /file.x
```

That will only match a top level file.x but not one lower down, in "want/file.x", say.