# Unable to ignore directory using gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Below is my directory structure.

```
parent_directory
 |--.gitignore
 |--static/
 |   |--js/
 |   |   |--encoding.js
 |   |--css
 |       |--parent.css
 |--tools/
 |    |--static/
 |    |   |--js/
 |    |   |--css/
 |    |--templates/
```

I want to ignore **outer** static directory. I tries `static/**/` , `static/`, `static/**` but nothing is working. Whenever I edit `encoding.js` file it appears in tracked file list.

Steps I followed - 
1. Edited the .gitignore file and added pattern [all three one at a time]
2. Edited the file encoding.js
3. checked git status. File appeared in tracked file zone.

How should I add the pattern so that any folder or file in `./static/` folder is not tracked.

Update 1: Added static in the .gitignore file. Still not working. See the attached image. [**Solved**]

[image]
[image]

Update 2: adding static in .gitignore file ignores the /tools/static/ directory as well which is not suppose to happen. Just the outer static directory should be ignored.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `static` and it should be ignored. I think the slash is confusing it.

Comment: Just tested this and it worked. I've posted an answer.

Comment: Just double checking, but are you sure that `encoding.js` isn't already in version control somewhere? Because that overrides your `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `static` to your .gitignore file.

*The forward slash is stopping git from finding the directory.*

**Edit 1:** You may need to run `git rm --cached static` if the folder is already being tracked by git.

**Edit 2:** The poster's criteria have changed and they *only* want to ignore the `static` folder in the root directory.

Just add `/static` to your .gitignore file *(and remove `static`)*.

This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473102/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-the-root-of-my-git-repository-but-include-it-fur) in another Question.

Comment: tried your solution. Still not working. updated question.

Comment: That's weird. I tested my solution on a clean repo.

Comment: @User42 I updated the answer. Try what I've suggested.

Comment: that worked. So what this command do exactly and when should I run it.

Comment: `git rm` is used to remove a file/folder from being tracked. The `--cached` means that the file/folder isn't deleted from your file system.

Comment: Just came to know that using suggested approach, my files in  /tools/static/ folder are also getting ignored.

Comment: @User42 You can't ignore a directory without ignoring the files it contains.

Comment: Please go through the question again. I want to ignore the /parent_directory/static/ folder and not /parent_directory/tools/static/ folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121700/discussion-between-brandon-ibbotson-and-user42).